# jquery remove html in radio button value

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button list that gets dynamically generated by an XML feed from USPS an example below:

```
<div id="pnlCartAllowsShippingMethodSelection">
    <span id="ShipSelectionMsg"><p><b>Please select the desired shipping method below:</b></p></span>
    <input type="radio" name="ShippingMethodID" id="ShippingMethodID3" value="41|Express Mail International|55.60|0.00">&nbsp;Express Mail International $55.60 (USD)<span id="shippingdescription"> - Delivery in 3-5 Business Days*</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ShippingMethodID" id="ShippingMethodID3" value="9|Priority Mail International|42.58|0.00">&nbsp;Priority Mail International $42.58 (USD)<span id="shippingdescription"> - Delivery in 6-10 Business Days*</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ShippingMethodID" id="ShippingMethodID3" value="67|First-Class Package International Service<sup>TM</sup>**|19.53|0.00">&nbsp;First-Class Package International Service<sup>™</sup>** $19.53 (USD)<br>
    <input type="hidden" name="RequireShippingSelection" value="true">
</div>
```

I'd like to loop through all `<inputs>` and find any `<sup>TM</sup>` tags and remove them from the `value` field.

I believe I'd need to use the `.each()` function. Just not sure what function to use inside the each function

```
$('#pnlCartAllowsShippingMethodSelection input").each(function() {
    $(this).
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.remove()`:

```
$('#pnlCartAllowsShippingMethodSelection sup').remove();
```

For the radio buttons, you could do something like this:

```
$('#pnlCartAllowsShippingMethodSelection input').val(function(index, value) {
    return value.replace(/<sup>TM<\/sup>/g, '');
});
```

Comment: Works great for the text, what can I do to remove it from the value of the radio button?

Comment: I'm running that in the console window of firebug and it doesn't seem to pull it out.

Comment: Yep, works great, the difference in mine is that it was actually putting in the html TM character vs the string 'TM' once I changed that it worked great.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#pnlCartAllowsShippingMethodSelection sup").remove()
```